# BigQuery Create a unique group from Sequence of Results

Tags: google-bigquery

What are the options how to create a group from a sequence of results - see below the example table.  I want to generate the Desired_Outcome column such that each sequence  of passes or fails has a unique ID.

A description or how any examples work would also be greatly appreciated TIA.

I'm not allowed to attach images yet but a link is below to the table

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM3uZ.png)

Comment: Hold on while I edit the table sorry..

Comment: Should all be ok with the link now